How can I disable what looks like the Most Recent Used List
I am using various apps under Parallel Space.  Even when all these apps are closed, looking at the running apps shows this line of icons.  It looks like the MRU (Most Recent Used) list.  Not only does it show what apps I have used, one can click on the icons to start those apps.
I don't know what this line of icons (or feature) is called.  How do I get rid of it?
I am using

Note 20 Ultra
Android 13
Nova Launcher



For Samsung devices

Open the Recents screen
Tap the overflow menu (3-dots) on the top-right
Select Settings
Switch off Show recommended apps

